# Adding Text to Jquery SlideShow

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm new to jquery i'm trying to add text to my slideshow,I only want to add text with descriptions to but every time i add a li tag the slideshow stops i cant figure the problem?

```
<div id="slideshow">

    <img src="http://s5.postimg.org/mcs14gnef/cully_slider_foundation.jpg"><alt=1>
    <img src="http://s5.postimg.org/psfk09v93/cully_slider2.jpg"><alt=2>
    <img src="http://s5.postimg.org/72nkjj2if/cully_slider3.jpg"><alt=3>
    <img src="http://s5.postimg.org/dj14nd0fr/cully_slider4.jpg"><alt=4>

    </div>



#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}



function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Comment: What the `<alt=1>` element is supposed to do? HTML defines an `alt` *attribute*, for example: `<img src="....." alt="1">`.

Comment: How are you adding the text? Could you give us a code example of that?

Comment: Also, there's some CSS missing to make this slideshow work. There must be some CSS to hide the elements that are not active, and some to show the one that is.